# Fetch video id from a youtube playlist using PHP-SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml, youtube-api

I'm fetching a few videos from a Youtube playlist using SimpleXML and the Youtube API. I managed to get the title of each video but can´t figure out how to get the video IDs.

How do I get the `<yt:videoid>` tag?

This is what I got so far:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/ ID ');

$videos=array();

foreach ($xml->entry as $video) {
      $vid = array();
      $vid['title'] = $video->title; // <- This Works

      $media = $video->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
      $yt = $media->group->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
      $vid['id']=$yt->videoid;  // <- Not Working

      $videos[]=$vid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess here: You are just outputting 'title' but you try to do something else with 'videoid'? Because what you are adding to the `$vid` array are not strings, but `SimpleXMLElement`-Objects. You have to cast them manually:

```
$vid['id']= (string) $yt->videoid;
```

Other than that, your code works OK.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
$vid['id']=$yt->videoid;
```